# Should I uninstall Mail incompatible plug in which are disabled/inactive after Mountain Lion upgrade?

Tags: mail.app, macos

I previously installed Herald for Mail under Lion.

When I rebooted after the installation of Mountain Lion, Mail told me the plug in was incompatible and it is now disabled or inactive.

> 1. Was the mail plug in properly uninstalled and is it just disabled?
> 2. Should I try to uninstall the mail plug in properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That always happens when a new version of Mail comes out, the Herald dev needs some time in order to get the plugin compatible.

If you still want to use Herald, just ignore it and watch [@heraldapp](https://twitter.com/heraldapp) on Twitter, to be notified when the update is available.

If you don't want Herald anymore, uninstall it by using the uninstaller in the herald.zip download file.

Comment: So I need to uninstall it manually ?

Comment: Not necessarily. Mail deactivates (uninstalls) incompatible plug-ins automatically and moves them to `~/Library/Mail/Bundles (deactivated)`.